# Ricci curvature under Ricci flow

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, ricci-flow

In fact ,I got stuck in some compute. Let $B_{ijkl}=g^{pr}g^{qs}R_{piqj}R_{rksl}$,
in the below picture,I can't compute out the 1 and 2 equation above red line.

In the first, I know how to get $\Delta R_{ik}$, but the other part ,it's seemly too complex that I can't compute out.

In the second , I think I need some exchange equation of $B_{ijkl}$.

Besides, I always get stuck in compute , when I read paper about Ricci flow.
What should I do? And there are so many index that let me dazzle, whether there are some easy way to deal it ?

Thanks for useful hint or answer.Sorry for my poor English.

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

[image]

[image]

Comment: Well I would say writing this in terms of indices is probably the easiest way to deal with it. On one hand you can use normal coordinate to simplify calculations, on the other hand you there is no such representation (in terms of indices), then it is even harder to compute. You need to be familiar with this. As far as I know, almost all papers/books on Ricci flow starts the calculations right at page 1.

Comment: @John  I also think I need to be familiar with this , But I think it's good  to make a soft that help checking the index and giving some possible transformation. I feel assistant software is good for situation of many index.  But now ,I want to get the way of computing 1 and  2, do you have any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1) If we use normal coordinate, then the term in second line is
$$
-g^{jl}g^{pq} (R_{pjkl} R_{qi} + R_{ipkl} R_{qj} + R_{ijpl} R_{qk} +
R_{ijkp} R_{ql} ) $$

$$ = -g^{pq} ( R_{pk} R_{qi} + R_{ipkl} R_{ql} +
R_{ip} R_{qk} + R_{ilkp} R_{ql} ) $$

$$ =-2g^{pq} R_{pk} R_{qi}\underbrace{ - g^{pq} (  R_{ipkl} R_{ql} +
 R_{ilkp} R_{ql} )}_{=A} $$

The term in the first line is $$ 2g^{jl} ( B_{ijkl} - B_{ijlk} -
B_{il jk} + B_{ikjl} ) = 2g^{jl} ( B_{ijkl} - 2B_{ijlk} )
 + \underbrace{2B_{ikll} }_{=B} $$
so that $$ A+ B = - g^{pq} (  R_{ipkl} R_{ql} +
 R_{ilkp} R_{ql} )
 +2 R_{piqk } R_{pq} =0 $$

by Bianchi identity

(2) Recall $$ B_{ijkl} = R_{piqj} R^{p\ q}_{\ k\ l} $$
 so that $$ g^{jl} B_{ijkl}= R_{piqj} R^{p\ qj}_{\ k} = R_{piqj} R^{qjp}_k $$
 $$ g^{jl} B_{ijlk}= R_{piqj} R^{pj q}_{\ \ \ k} $$

The term in third line can be expanded into $$
 R_{piqj} R^{p\ qj}_{\ k}  - R_{pjqi} R^{p\ qj}_{\ k} - R_{piqj} R^{pjq}_{\ \ \ k} +
 R_{pjqi } R^{pjq}_{\ \ \ k}$$

$$ =
 R_{piqj} R^{qjp}_{\ \ \ k}  - R_{pjqi} R^{qjp}_{\ \ \ k} -
 g^{jl} B_{ijlk}  +
 R_{qjpi } R^{qjp}_{\ \ \ k}$$

$$ = g^{jl} B_{ijkl} -  g^{jl} B_{ijlk}-
 g^{jl} B_{ijlk}  +
g^{jl} B_{ijkl}$$ Hence we complete the proof

Comment: Why did the term $g^{jp}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial t} g_{pq} \right) g^{ql} R_{ijkl}$ vanish? What did you do with it?

Comment: I did nothing about the term. Please read things in original posting.

Comment: I'm very sorry if I seemed rude. It's just that I've read your post several times over now and I can't figure it out. In normal coordinates where $g_{ij} = \delta_{ij}$ that term would come out to be $-2R_{jk}R_{ijkl}$, but I can't see it anywhere in your post. Again, sorry. But where did it go? I'm not seeing it, would really appreciate it if you explained that a little bit more

Comment: I eventually managed to track down my mistake, but thanks for your reply anyway!    You indeed did nothing with the term and I was definitely wrong.